# Slidedown content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working code for slidedown menu content.

However I'm having some trouble with keeping the active which is the same as the hover state on when you click a button and taking it off when you click it to close it.

[Here is my working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/XUEFx/5/)

```
// IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
    // ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
    $(this).addClass('on');

    // OPEN THE SLIDE
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
}
```

Comment: $(this) is not pointing accordionButton but on $('.accordionButton[i]').next().is(':hidden')

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {

        //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
        $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');

        //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
        var self = this;
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal', function() {
             $(self).toggleClass('on', $(this).is(':visible'));                                   
        });
     });
```

[Try the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ardydedase/jTm8K/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.accordionButton').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.accordionButton').not(this).removeClass('on');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vABFM/2/)

Comment: Arun think you broke the close functionality now and also when you click another content- the red suppose to stay on the previous until you close it manually. Thanks though im still trying on my end.!